# 508 compliance for radio buttons, position issue on IE and Chrome

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, section508

I need to make the radio buttons accessible to blind users. Currently the screen reader is picking up all the labels and value for the radio buttons correctly. But it is not reading the position of the radio button.

For example: (This one is works example that reads the position correctly but only on chrome)

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose a shipping method:</legend>
<div role="radiogroup">
    <input id="overnight" type="radio" role="radio" name="shipping" value="overnight">
    <label for="overnight">Overnight</label>
    <input id="twoday" type="radio" name="shipping" role="radio" value="twoday">
    <label for="twoday">Two day</label>
    <input id="ground" type="radio" name="shipping" role="radio" value="ground">
    <label for="ground">Ground</label>
    <input id="sky" type="radio" name="shipping" role="radio" value="sky">
    <label for="sky">sky</label>
    <input id="never" type="radio" name="shipping" role="radio" value="never">
    <label for="never">Never hahahaha</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

If the "Two day" is selected on chrome. screen reader will read it as "Choose a shipping method: Two day radio button checked. 2 of 5".

But on IE screen reader will read it as "List Box Two Day radio button checked".

Now the real problem is here. I have a directive that generates the labels and value for the radio buttons. It is loaded into the DOM with ng-repeat directive.
And with each iteration a div is getting inserted between the input elements. Because of which Jaws is not picking up the position.

Below is the HTML partial.

```
<fieldset>
                <legend class="sr-only">Source Types</legend>
                    <div class="form-inline" role="radiogroup"                      >
                    <!--div for source identifiers radios-->
                       <div ng-repeat="sourceType in sourceTypes" class="form-group" role="radio">
                                <input type="radio"
                                       name="sourceType"
                                       id='{{sourceType.typeId}}'
                                       ng-value='sourceType.typeValue'
                                       ng-model='formModel.sourceType'
                                       ng-disabled="disableInputFields"
                                       ng-change="changeSourceType(sourceType)"/>
                            <label for="{{sourceType.typeId}}">
                                {{sourceType.typeLabel}}
                            </label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
```

And here is the rendered content:

```
<fieldset>
                <legend class="sr-only">Source Types</legend>
                    <div class="form-inline" role="radiogroup">
                    <!--div for source identifiers radios-->
                       <!-- ngRepeat: sourceType in sourceTypes --><div ng-repeat="sourceType in sourceTypes" class="form-group ng-scope" role="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="sourceType" id="secbtn" ng-value="sourceType.typeValue" ng-model="formModel.sourceType" ng-disabled="disableInputFields" ng-change="changeSourceType(sourceType)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" value="sec">
                            <label for="secbtn" class="ng-binding">
                                Source Type 1
                            </label>
                       </div><!-- end ngRepeat: sourceType in sourceTypes --><div ng-repeat="sourceType in sourceTypes" class="form-group ng-scope" role="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="sourceType" id="generatedbtn" ng-value="sourceType.typeValue" ng-model="formModel.sourceType" ng-disabled="disableInputFields" ng-change="changeSourceType(sourceType)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" value="gen">
                            <label for="generatedbtn" class="ng-binding">
                                Source Type 2
                            </label>
                       </div><!-- end ngRepeat: sourceType in sourceTypes -->
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
```

TLDR : How to make Jaws screen reader to read the radio buttons correctly including the position of the selected/active button on both IE 11 and chrome.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: adding role attribute with "radio" value fixes the issue on chrome but on IE its not picking up the labels. if I just focus on IE, is it possible to make the screen reader read the position of the radio button?

Answer (score 2):

This is browser dependent. You shouldn't care.

Here, the problem is not your code, nor JAWS. It's the way Internet Explorer implements the accessibility API.

IE is not announcing the position of the selected element to the accessibility API. It's just a different implementation, and changing your code won't have any effect in the way Internet Explorer communicates with screenreaders.

Comment: Yup I found this article to support your claim. http://www.ssbbartgroup.com/blog/how-browsers-interact-with-screen-readers-and-where-aria-fits-in-the-mix/